# What does it mean scalable/modular code in web development?

Tags: scalability

I was watching this video with Airbnb co-founder, at 5:57 he starts talking about how the code he had written in the early stages was modular and scalable:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLVR6Wbmvqw

Can someone please explain, in regards to web/app development,:

1) what does it mean to write scalable/modular code?

2) How could one educate him/her self to write a scalable/modular code for web/app development?

3) When Nathan is talking about scalable/modular code, does he mean his Ruby code was scalable?

4) What parts/components of the code need to be written in a scalable/modular manner, so that if the number of users was increasing suddenly, things don't start to crash?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can start by reading this book on scaling Flickr. http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596102357.do The book is very dated. But many of the underlying principles still apply and most of the services built/operated by Flickr internally are now made available by cloud providers so that you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just came to know about Google Cloud and AWS, I guess that is also somethin to look at

Comment: Sure. At what stage are you in? Can you build web apps that run on a single server / your machine? If not, you can focus on that and learn about scaling when needed.